# What are the ways to reduce startup time of a Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one Spring boot app that takes around 32 seconds for startup. I tried to reduce this startup time using Spring Native, and the startup time reduced to 9.2 seconds. I want to know if there are more ways to reduce this time further?

I am using PostgreSQL for DB Management, HikariCP for connection pooling and JPA repository.

Comment: Are you talking about running the app in .jar or from an IDEA? Consider checking the machine where you are trying to run app. Longer compile and startup time may also be due to your machine's power capability.

Comment: Such performance tuning is highly application specific - you should just google materials and learn more about that. One way could be marking your beans as Lazy and entity mappings as well.